# How to pass a field bigger than 2000 characters from a SuiteScript script to a Suitelet script in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have coded a suiteScript (V1.0) form that loads a sublist. I check some lines in this sublist and I need to create a file with this line and another information and save it into the the file cabinet.

I was thinking create the field and populate the data with SuiteScript functions and pass the info by POST to the Suitelet script but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a Suitelet with a sublist?
If so,if the list is editable, you can get the sublist values through NetSuite api (request.getLineItemValue) on the POST action, you don't have to send it manually.